# Can you assign Json values to a list in C#?

Tags: c#, json

Newbie here having a difficult time trying to assign these values from a json file to a list in C#. This is the json file:

```json
{
   "timezone":"Australia",
   "current":{
      "temp":5.96,
      "feels_like":4.8,
      "wind_speed":1.7,
      "wind_deg":286,
      "weather":[
         {
            "description":"clear sky",
            "icon":"01n"
         }
      ]
   },
   "daily":[
      {
         "temp":{
            "day":9.99,
            "min":4.76,
            "max":10.06,
            "night":7.85,
         },
         "feels_like":{
            "day":9.99,
            "night":7.85,
         },
         "wind_speed":1.7,
         "wind_deg":286,
         "weather":[
            {
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ],
      },
      {
         "temp":{
            "day":10.89,
            "min":4.5,
            "max":10.94,
            "night":4.5,
         },
         "feels_like":{
            "day":9.5,
            "night":2.83,
         },
         "wind_speed":2.5,
         "wind_deg":359,
         "weather":[
            {
               "description":"overcast",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ],
      }
   ]
}
```

I think these are the values that are required for the list:

```cs
    public class Forecast
    {
        public float temp { get; set; }
        public float feels_like { get; set; }

        public float day { get; set; }
        public float min { get; set; }
        public float max { get; set; }
        public float night { get; set; }

        public float wind_speed { get; set; }
        public int wind_deg { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried to look through some documentation and I am not quite sure how to add values from "temp" or "feels_like" or "weather" to the list:

```json
         "temp":{
            "day":9.99,
            "min":4.76,
            "max":10.06,
            "night":7.85,
         },
```

```json
         "feels_like":{
            "day":9.99,
            "night":7.85,
         },
```

```json
         "weather":[
            {
               "description":"overcast clouds",
               "icon":"04d"
            }
         ],
```

So far my intended outcome is to just use `Console.WriteLine` to print one value from the list.

For example, this could be the weather description for the second forecast day being "overcast". Another example is the maximum temperature for the first forecast day being "10.06". One more is the current temperature being "5.96".

Comment: Your JSON structure doesn't match whatsoever with your C# models. For example, `temp` in JSON is an object with 4 properties, but in C# it's a float. Are you even able to parse the information into c# to begin with?

Comment: Try using https://quicktype.io/csharp to generate your C# classes, because what you have so far is incorrect (see comment above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var output= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CountryWeather>( json);
```

or if you have several countries in one file

```
var outputList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryWeather>>( json);
```

and classes

```
public class Weather
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Current
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public double feels_like { get; set; }
    public double wind_speed { get; set; }
    public int wind_deg { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
}

public class Temp
{
    public double day { get; set; }
    public double min { get; set; }
    public double max { get; set; }
    public double night { get; set; }
}

public class FeelsLike
{
    public double day { get; set; }
    public double night { get; set; }
}

public class Daily
{
    public Temp temp { get; set; }
    public FeelsLike feels_like { get; set; }
    public double wind_speed { get; set; }
    public int wind_deg { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
}

public class CountryWeather
{
    public string timezone { get; set; }
    public Current current { get; set; }
    public List<Daily> daily { get; set; }
}
```